# Visual Studio 2017 Angular 2 error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am trying to use angular 2 in visual studio 2017 but getting lost of error while building the application. Here is the package.json file

Package.json

```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.6",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
    }
}
```

I have used the typescript setting as mention in the below setting files

Typescript seting

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "app",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/node_modules"

  ],

  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Here are the list of errors

```
   Error    TS6133  'object' is declared but never used.
Error   TS2457  Type alias name cannot be 'object'
Error   TS2345  Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
Error   TS2345  Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
Error   TS2457  Build:Type alias name cannot be 'object'
Error   TS2345  Build:Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
Error   TS2345  Build:Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'
```

.

Comment: Well, the errors are clear. You are trying to assign a `number` to a variable of type `object`. You have declared a variable of type `object` but you never use it.

Comment: I have not used in anywhere in the ts file. Just I have setup the angular 2 in visual studio 2017

Comment: I have resolve the Object error. How, can I resolve the second error can you please let me know -  Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'

Comment: So the scaffold is broken. See if there are some files added by the creator of the scaffold project, look at them and see if there are any `number`assignment to an `object` variable. Also, i suggest you use Angular 4. It is fully compatible with Angular 2.